# AWS RDS metrics for individual database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using the AWS Aurora Serverless V2 with MySQL 8 and I have a few instances of that.
I've create a dashboard on CloudWatch with some metrics about each instance (CPU utilization, queries volume, number of connections, etc).

Now I would like to know if it is possible to get some metrics for each individual database on each server/instance.

I have one database for every customer in my system. I want to know, for example, how much each customer is using the resources of an instance.

Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: If you SHOW DATABASES; how many rows are counted in the result?  Do you really mean you have one database for EACH customer in your system?

Comment: What is result of SELECT @@performance_schema;  ?

Comment: I have 7 instances of Aurora Serverles V2 with MySQL 8. For each one of them, if a run a SHOW DATABASES I will get about 100 lines, ie, about 100 databases.

Comment: On any one of the instances, what is the result of SELECT @@performance_schema; ?